# Bashscript with Gnuplot on .csv File

Tags: bash, csv, gnuplot

I would like to write a little bash script, which simply asks the user to enter a Country and a Item.
The script shall open gnuplot and plot some data (the Order Date and Total Profit for the Country and Item) from a .csv and safe in .png

These are the first few lines (100k in total):

```
Country,Item Type,Order Date,Total Profit
Afghanistan,Baby Food,1/10/2010,672649.62
Afghanistan,Baby Food,1/23/2010,833406.84
Afghanistan,Baby Food,10/14/2011,893894.50
Afghanistan,Baby Food,10/20/2013,38919.16
Afghanistan,Baby Food,11/10/2015,51189.24
Afghanistan,Baby Food,11/19/2014,471247.76
```

My input in gnuplot terminal:

```
set title 'sales'
set xlabel 'date'
set ylabel 'profit'
set datafile separator ','
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m/%d/%y"
plot 100k.csv u 3:4 w lines
```

If I use this manual in the Gnuplot Terminal, it plots the wanted data. The problem is that it doesn't ignore the "headline" (Country,Item Type,Order Date,Total Profit)

Comment: Could you please show us your script? It's hard to read from where I stand :)

Comment: What is your filename? Put your filename in single quotes. Try `plot '100k.csv' u 3:4 w lines`.

Comment: @Jacques Gaudin i dont have any script right now. i wanted to plot it manually before i write the script.

Comment: @theozh i already tried that thanks :)

Comment: does `grep -q \" youfile.csv && echo quoted` outputs `quoted`?

Comment: @Fravadona nope, it outputs nothing. Also no error line

Comment: OK, it means that your CSV file does not need a specialized parser. @Thomas answer should work fine; if not then you may have CRLF (Windows) line endings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not fully clear to me whether you are looking for a bash-script or a gnuplot-script, probably both.
What I understand is that you want to make a call from the command line to generate some plots.
So, you need to filter data from a CSV file and generate and save a plot to disk.

With the following suggestion you call gnuplot from the command line via:

```
gnuplot -c "SO70774684.gp" "Afghanistan" "Baby Food"
```

and gnuplot is doing all for you, i.e. filtering and generation of the PNG graph.

I assume that the entries are sorted by date, otherwise a line plot doesn't make too much sense or data needs to be sorted first.
You are not specifying too many details, hence there is a lot of room for adjustments.

**Data:** `'SO70774684.csv'` with some more lines added.

```
Country,     Item Type, Order Date, Total Profit
Afghanistan, Baby Food,  1/10/2010, 672649.62
Belgium,     Baby Food,  1/10/2010, 1111
Afghanistan, Baby Food,  1/23/2010, 833406.84
Cyprus,      Baby Food,  1/23/2010, 2222
Afghanistan, Baby Food, 10/14/2011, 893894.50
Denmark,     Baby Food, 10/14/2011, 3333
Afghanistan, Baby Food, 10/20/2013, 38919.16
Estonia,     Baby Food, 10/14/2011, 4444
Afghanistan, Baby Food, 11/19/2014, 471247.76
France,      Baby Food, 10/14/2011, 5555
Afghanistan, Baby Food, 11/10/2015, 51189.24
Germany,     Baby Food, 10/14/2011, 6666
Belgium,     Baby Food,  1/10/2010, 1000
Cyprus,      Baby Food,  1/23/2010, 2000
Denmark,     Baby Food, 10/14/2011, 3000
Estonia,     Baby Food, 10/14/2011, 4000
France,      Baby Food, 10/14/2011, 5000
Germany,     Baby Food, 10/14/2011, 6000
```

**Code:** (gnuplot script file `'SO70774684.gp'`)

```
### create gnuplot graph from command line call
reset session

FILE    = 'SO70774684.csv'
Country = ARG1
Item    = ARG2

set datafile separator comma
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m/%d/%Y"

set term pngcairo size 640,384 font ",10"
set output sprintf("%s,%s.png",Country,Item)

set ylabel "Total profit" font ",11"
set format x "%m\n%Y"
set boxwidth 1.0 relative
set style fill solid 0.3
set key noautotitle
set grid x,y

set title sprintf("%s: %s", Country, Item)

myFilter(colD,colF1,F1,colF2,F2) = strcol(colF1) eq F1 && strcol(colF2) eq F2 ? column(colD) : NaN
set datafile missing NaN

plot FILE u 3:(myFilter(4,1,Country,2,Item)) w lp pt 7 lc "red"

set output
### end of code
```

**Result:** (File: `'Afghanistan,Baby Food.png'`)

[image]

Comment: If i use Gnuplot on the script, it tells me "line 1: warning optional axis name"
and "line1: ';' expected

if i delete the reset session line, it gives me an error that my variable isnt declared

Comment: @Thomas which operating system, which gnuplot version? How do you start the script, from gnuplot console or from system command line? What is the current working directory, where are gnuplot and the data located?

Comment: Im using Ubuntu with Gnuplot 4.6. Im starting the script directly from the terminal. Working directory and data (script and .csv) is the same directory. Gnuplot directory is different. When i open Gnuplot on terminal and put the few comands (which i wrote on top of the post) then it works and plots the data , but only if i delete the "headline" (Country,Item Type,Order Date,Total Profit)

Comment: @Thomas Oops, gnuplot 4.6? Which version 4.6.0 or 4.6.5? Why a 10 year old version? We are at version 5.4 now. So, what again happens if you type in the Ubuntu command line `gnuplot -c "SO70774684.gp" "Afghanistan" "Baby Food"`. Alternatively, if you are working from the gnuplot command line, change the two lines with `ARG1` and `ARG2` to `Country = "Afghanistan"` and `Item = "Baby Food"` and start your script with `load "SO70774684.gp"`. Difficult to guess remotely what you are actually doing.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/54f18328cdd13b7b33aed04180c9c22a

this is what im trying to do. If i delete the "reset session" line, it gives me the error: "myscript.sh", line 1: undefined variable ARG1"

Comment: @Thomas  gnuplot 4.6 is probably too old to have this `-c` option. Try the alternative approach from the gnuplot console or update to a newer version.

Comment: yes if i try it from the gnuplot console and delete the line "set datafile missing NaN" it works. Just one more thing: how can i tell it, that the first line in the csv should be ignored?

Comment: @Thomas gnuplot 4.6 is too old for `set datafile missing NaN`. You can skip lines from the beginning, e.g. via `plot FILE u 1:2 skip 1 w lp`. Check `help skip`. Problem solved? Question answered?

Comment: yes that answered everything.
Thanks you very much for all ur effort :)